# how to push React Leaflet's attribution and map controls to the back

Tags: css, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

## what i'm trying to do

the user sees a map, built in React Leaflet / Leaflet.JS. The user can then click a CTA button that pops up a modal. The modal should be the "top layer" of the screen, with the website in the background.

## what's wrong

the attribution tag of the React Leaflet is over the top of the modal. I can also see the controls of the React Leaflet `MapContainer`. See screenshot below:
[image: screenshot of problem]

## what have i tried

before I did anything, the entire `<MapContainer>` React Leaflet component was over the top of the modal. By increasing the `zIndex` of my modal component to `999`, the above screenshot is seen. I have attempted to add `zIndex` within `style` props, as well as its own prop to both the `<MapContainer>` parent element and `TileLayer` child element, none of which fixes:

```js
  return (
    <MapContainer
      style={{ height: 600, width: "80%", margin: "auto" }}
      center={mapCentre}
      zoom={11}
      zIndex={-999}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Tiles style by <a href="https://www.hotosm.org/" target="_blank">Humanitarian OpenStreetMap Team</a> hosted by <a href="https://openstreetmap.fr/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap France</a>'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        zIndex={-999}
      />
      {locations}
    </MapContainer>
  );
```